# i think i found a bug in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was making asteroids in google chrome, wen i tried to press space + up arrow + left arrow, it did not detected left arrow!!!!

i tried with other browser windows, other combinations of keys and in edge, but it kept bugging, and only with space + arrow up + arrow left

can someone else try out the following code, that logs the keys detected?

```js
document.onkeydown=e=>console.log(e.code);
```

Comment: Working for me :)

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware problem. Look for "keyboard ghosting".

Comment: already looking :)

Comment: I can reproduce this. It's notable, that events and their properties are not a part of JavaScript standard, they're a part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

i looked at the comments and it seems like it is a hardware problem, called keyboard ghosting (the following image is a scrrenshot pressing space + arrow up + ARROW LEFT)
[image: PRESSING ARROW LEFT ALSO!!!]